# Python double for loop multiprocessing

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing, double

```
def dataSizeSelection(data, data_path, labels, sample_sz):

    data_set = []
    label_set = []
    sz_set = []
    
    for label in labels.values():
        dir = data_path + "/" + label
        sz_set.append(len(os.listdir(dir)))
    
    idx_start = 0
    
    for i, sz in enumerate(sz_set):
        idx_end = idx_start + sz
        idx = random.sample(range(idx_start, idx_end), sample_sz)
        idx_start += sz

        for j in idx:
            # data_set.append(np.array(data[j][0]))
            data_set.append(np.array(data[j][0]).flatten())
            label_set.append(data[j][1])
            
    return data_set, label_set
```

This code is for data pre-processing which selects the data with the fixed number(sample_sz). And this function also for making the 2D PIL data(data) into 1D numpy array.
I want to run this function by multiprocessing since it takes quite long runtime for large dataset. But, I don't know how to use multiprocessing (joblib or multiprocessing).

I tried to use Parallel in joblib but i don't know how to use it for double for loop and it seems that I can pass only one argument in Parallel.

Comment: seems like a very sequential code. slapping multiprocessing on top of it will only make it slower.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Then, is there any way to speed up the code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: nothing much can be done inside this function , maybe swap `random.sample` with `np.random.randint` but that won't speed it up noticeably, you should instead change `data` to be 2 numpy arrays and index them directly with `idx` instead of the second loop, this could be faster or slower depending on the size of each element in `data` ... so you cannot do much really.

Comment: Possibly calling `.flatten()` inside the loop could be slowing it down. Try using flatten outside of the for loops. `flatten = np.array(data_set).flatten()` and just use your commented out part as is `data_set.append(np.array(data[j][0]))` . Also what the other comment above suggested.

Comment: @kconsiglio `flatten` returns a view, so it is not slow, it does no work.